# Specifying parameters for block_load

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm attempting to load a Book Navigation block programmatically inside another block. After doing some research it seems that I need to take advantage of the bload_load function. I'm using

```
$block = block_load('book', 'navigation');
$output =_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
$res_output = drupal_render($res_output);
print render($res_output);
```

However there is no output. I have a feeling that the parameters for block_load are incorrect. I based them off of what the URL contained

```
/admin/structure/block/manage/book/navigation/configure
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with [`block_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/function/block_load/7); you've specified the correct parameters with the function (the module is 'block' & the delta for the block is 'navigation'). The problem is your typo prevents the render array going to the `print_render()`. It should be:

```
$res_output = drupal_render($output);
```

Comment: I'm close, I was able to render a specific block using this method but it seems to only work on blocks that were directly created. I was able to generate the block from this url mydomain.com/admin/structure/block/manage/block/103/configure using block_load('block','104') but with the book navigation  at mydomain.com/admin/structure/block/manage/book/navigation/configure I have been unsuccessful. I've tried block_load('book','navigation'), ('block','navigation') and ('blook','book','navigation') with no luck

Comment: Look @ the `block_load()` function, it is querying the block table based on the module & delta. The block (1st param) should always be 'book' & the delta might vary (the default is 'navigation'); check your DB table. Regardless, it `$output` contains block render array, it needs to be based to `drupal_render()` for it to work.